# Sceneform sdk object not move on wall

Tags: arcore, sceneform

I use sample example of SceneForm SDK but in this when we put object on detected floor we can move not on wall. How can this be resolved?

```
arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener(
                (HitResult hitResult, Plane plane, MotionEvent motionEvent) -> {
                    if (andyRenderable == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                   /* if (plane.getType() != Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING) {
                        return;
                    }*/

                    // Create the Anchor.
                    Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
                    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
                    anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

                    // Create the transformable andy and add it to the anchor.
                    TransformableNode andy = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
                    andy.setParent(anchorNode);
                    andy.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
                    andy.select();
                    andy.setEnabled(true);
                });
```

Comment: Sceneform SDK 1.0 does not support transformation on vertical planes out of the box. However, this feature is coming in an upcoming release. You can track the status of it here: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/24

Answer (score 2):

on the new version of SCENEFORM SDK, v1.3.0 issue is resolved.
use this in app level gradle

implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.3.0"

and use this to project level gradle

classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.3.0'